# Custom Styling not getting applied to the kendo grid in Angular 6

Tags: angular, telerik, angular6, kendo-grid

Hi I am trying to add custom styling to the selected rows in kendo grid, but it is not getting applied.

Following is my code in css file of that component

```
:host ::ng-deep .modal-dialog .k-grid td.k-state-selected, .k-grid tr.k-state- 
 selected>td {
background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

I had contacted telerik support they asked me to add encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None in ts file but after adding that the style is getting applied for all the components, so i am not able to find why its not getting applied.

In one of the question on stackoverflow i found **:host ::ng-deep** by adding this it will work so i tried but still its not working.

My Kendo-Grid is on Bootstrap Modal Popup.

Comment: Do you have any snippet? Refer to: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From your piece of code which you include we don't know what element does your browser had and how does your current code not working.

Comment: i am using kendo grid in component which is loaded on a bootstrap modal popup, i have eritten above code in css file of that particular component,but the style is getting applied to all the other components kendo grid also.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting? And check whether the style gets applied?

Comment: yes i inspected custom style is not getting applied if i dont use encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None in ts file, but when apply it its working but the issue is it is getting applied to all the other components also.

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255102/custom-styling-of-specific-component-getting-applied-to-all-the-components-in-an

Comment: Have you tried making a custom css which applied only to that component? ViewEncapsulation.None is letting your css everywhere.

Comment: but when i remove ViewEncapsulation.None its not getting applied even for that single component also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it worked for me by doing following changes

```
:host ::ng-deep .modal-dialog .k-grid td.k-state-selected,:host ::ng-deep .k-grid tr.k- 
state-selected>td {
background-color:lightgreen;
}
```